# Sonatype-Nexus-OSS-Include/exlude list

Tags: nexus

Can I add include or exclude list in my hosted/proxy repo in Nexus OSS? If so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in the professional version, but not the OSS version.  That requires the procurement suite.

See here for info: http://www.sonatype.com/books/nexus-book/reference/procure.html